# ruby file.read permission failed

Tags: ruby, file

Run into this issue in File.open("xxx.txt",'r');

```
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen
```

I am running the ruby script as user A, which is in group DEVELOPERS

The file is created by user B, which is also in group DEVELOPERS

The file has permission

```
-rw-r-----
```

run less as user A can show the content of the file

```
less xxx.txt     #good
```

finally, I am using absolute path of xxx.txt, so don't make this suggestion.

Comment: Please, put in the script `puts "USER: #{\`whoami\`}"` just before `File.open`  and share the output.

Comment: make sure that the parent directories of xxx.txt are readable by user A

Comment: Response to mudasobwa USER: A

Comment: When I try to write debug file like this
    debug=File.open('/home/A/debug.txt','r');
    debug.write("USER: #{`whoami`}");

The script complains "not opened for writing .... in 'write'"

Comment: Nobody can answer this?